# Использование Microsoft RDP Client в WinForm .NET Core

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core

Я создаю приложение с использованием Microsoft RDP Client в Windows Forms .NET Core 3.1, но я не могу загрузить сам компонент из COM-компонентов, есть ли другой вариант подключения этого компонента?
Проблема в том, что само приложение почти написано, за исключением реализации работы с ним, мне бы не хотелось переделывать все на .NET Framework

Comment: А у Вас используется RDP в приложении на клиентской стороне? или на серверной? То есть, Ваше приложение "подключается" куда то, или само разрешает к себе "подключаться"?

Comment: @S.H. Подключается к vds/vps

Comment: @S.H. я так понимаю придется все же на .NET Framework переделывать

Comment: Думаю, что да. я сам несколько раз встречался с тем, что привычные по Framework интеграции с COM- компонентами в проектах на NET Core - не работают. А что поделать? Кросплатформенность...